# Access 2000 database via ArcCatalog displays decimals as integers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, import, table, ms-access

I import an Access 2000 database through ArcCatalog. When I complete the process and check the attribute table, the values come not as decimals as they are in the database but as integer numbers. Why is that?

I have done this in the past successfully but now it is not working properly. Does it have to do with the decimal separator being a dot and not a comma? Does ArcGIS understand `.` as decimal point?

Process:

1. Excel file import to Access, save as Access 2000
2. ArCatalog connect database Microsoft Jet 4.0
3. open ArcMap and refresh ArcCatalog
4. take the database sheet and drop it on the table of contents
5. display xy data
6. data export data

And this is basically it. ArcGIS shows it as a double.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Would you be able to include the precise steps that you performed in your question, please?  That way it should be possible to repeat them without guessing.

Comment: What type of fields does ArcGIS show in the personal geodatabase (e.g. float, double, short, text, etc)?

Comment: Process: Excel file--> import to access, save as access 2000, arcatalog connect database microsoft jet 4.0 , open arcmap refresh arccatalog, take the database sheet and drop it to the table of contents, display xy data, data export data and this is basically it. It shows double

Comment: Dot vs comma may depend on a localization setting. I believe you can set it to either, but I imagine if you have it set one way and your data is the other, it might not work. Have you considered trying to go directly from Excel to Arc (Excel to Table tool, or just adding it)? What is the end goal/format? Note that while personal geodatabase files use the Access format, they do have some special properties so a mdb created from Access may not work as expected if trying to use it as a personal geodatabase.

Comment: excel works fine, but when it comes to large amount of rows access should be the only solution. the final goal is to map one of the attributes but if the values are rounded, then there is no point. for example there are some values 0,3 and they become 0 in the attribute. these represent costs, so 0 is just fault.

Comment: My point is mainly that going to Access adds an extra step in the process, so it's not clear if the field definition problem is occurring between Excel and Access, or Access and ArcGIS. A possible workaround/solution is to save the spreadsheet as a csv file and use a [schema.ini file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000) to force ArcGIS to read that field as a double. Of course if there are commas in the data that aren't field separators, they could cause issues.

Comment: Have you checked the [numerical formatting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000003s000000) of that field to see if it's just a display issue?

Comment: I'm confused - near the end you say "ArcGIS shows it as a double" - but isn't that what you said you wanted that i.e. "the values come not as decimals as they are in the database but as integer numbers".  Also, except for your step 6 where you say "data export data [to ...?]" you seem to be viewing rather than importing the Access data.

Comment: PolyGeo, when I open the numerical formatting it has "double" checked, but in fact it is not. How would you import the access data in order to get decimal values? I recall doing this the same way some time ago and there was no issue at all.